# Регулярные выражения и знак тире(-)

Tags: регулярные-выражения, django

Как научить джанго вопринимать урлы в которых встречаются дефисы?
Вот часть из urls.py

```
(r'^catalog/(?P<sub>\w+)/(?P<it>\w+)/(?P<spec>\w+)/$',specification),
```

Вроде бы все хорошо,но как только появляются дефисы в адресе-выкидывает 404 страничку(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[-\w]+` вместо `\w+`

Comment: LinnTroll-спасибо.Взлетело

Answer (score 3):

Вероятно, это происходит потому, что:
`\w` - синоним `[[:word:]]` - Буквенный или цифровой символ или знак подчёркивания, т.е.  дефиса там нет. Надо вместо `\w` использовать группу символов, получится что-то вроде `[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+`

Comment: Долго писал, меня опередили!!! ))